# How to do gitpush using jgit API?

Tags: java, git, maven, api, jgit

I have used below **code** to do push.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,GitAPIException
{ 
  Repository localRepo = new 
  FileRepository("C:\\Users\\Joshi\\Desktop\\demo");
  Git git = new Git(localRepo);

// add remote repo:
  RemoteAddCommand remoteAddCommand = git.remoteAdd();
  remoteAddCommand.setName("origin");
  try {
    remoteAddCommand.setUri(new 
    URIish("https://bitbucket.org/nidhi011/bxc"));
    System.out.println("file Added");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// you can add more settings here if needed
remoteAddCommand.call();
git.commit().setMessage( "commited" ).call();

// push to remote:
PushCommand pushCommand = git.push();
pushCommand.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("username", "password"));
// you can add more settings here if needed
pushCommand.call();
}
```

and my **error** is

```
file Added

Exception in thread "main" 
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.WrongRepositoryStateException: Cannot commit on 
a repo with state: BARE
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.call(CommitCommand.java:171)
at maven_git.push.main(push.java:38)
```

After running the above code I got this exception error please help me to solve out the jgit push command. And yes One more thing when  I exceutes this code it make config file in my local directory " demo" folder I can't understand that.

Comment: **Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Nothing to push.** Maybe you need a git.add and a git.commit first?

Comment: @jonhid sir  yes I have done commit then I also get error of                     "Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.WrongRepositoryStateException: Cannot commit on a repo with state: BARE
 at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.call(CommitCommand.java:171)
 at maven_git.push.main(push.java:38)"

Comment: Is your directory `demo` a Git repository before launching your Java program?

Comment: @MincongHuang yes it is , having .git folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're several lines that are incorrect in your code. Let's take a look together.

#### Open Git Repository

Opening a Git repository using `FileRepository` is tricky. This is an internal API, where the given string is the location of the repository metadata (the `.git` folder). In other words, it is used to construct a Git bare repository. You can prove it by calling the `Repository#isBare()`:

```
Repository localRepo = new FileRepository("C:\\Users\\Joshi\\Desktop\\demo");
System.out.println(localRepo.isBare()); // true
```

After using this API, the created repository is a BARE repository. You *cannot* commit to a bare repository because it doesn't have a workspace. That's why you've exception saying:

> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.WrongRepositoryStateException: Cannot commit on 
>   a repo with state: BARE

A better way is to use `Git#open()`. Note that you should close the Git repository after using it. So I'm using the try-with-resources statement here:

```
try (Git git = Git.open(new File("C:\\Users\\Joshi\\Desktop\\demo"))) {
    // Add your logic here ...
}
```

#### Add Files to Git

Before commit the changes, you need to add them to the index, to prepare the content staged for the next commit. For example:

```
git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
```

Notice that this is completely different from `RemoteAddCommand`: we are adding file content, while `RemoteAddCommand` adds a new remote URL. In native Git commands, they're respectively:

```
git add .
git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/nidhi011/bxc
```

#### Commit

You're correct about this part.

#### Push

If the local branch is not checked out from a [tracking branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches), then you would need to precise the remote branch name in your push-command.

```
git.push().setRemote("origin").add("master").call();
```

If the credentials were incorrect, user would not be authorized for pushing the changes. In this case, a `TransportException` will be thrown. You can add additional logic for exception handling:

```
try {
    git.push().setRemote("origin").add("master").call();
} catch (TransportException e) {
    // Add your own logic here, for example:
    System.out.println("Username or password incorrect.");
}
```

Comment: what to write in tempDir sir ?

Comment: Oops, sorry @NidhiJoshi. I updated my answer now. It is the file path of your repository.

Comment: okk thank you so much Iam completed with my coding but one thing I  need to do is to  add validation what are the steps to be followed

Comment: Could you precise what do you want to validate, @NikitaJ?

Comment: like for url it is should be authenticate otherwise should pass error message and for credentials like username and password if it is not matching it should pass message like "Incorrect password" like this can you help me in it using coding explaination

Comment: okay sir but can you write the syntax to take user input at run time like how to take url, username and password by user

Comment: I recommend the article [JGit Authentication Explained](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/) for different auth modes in JGit and [Java tutorial: Java Scanner class](https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class) for scanning the user inputs.   I hope they're useful for you. @NikitaJ

Comment: okk, Earliarly I have taken reference from the code affine authentication but im not getting particular ans that how to take input from user at run time